# Magento Displaying Wrong Layout for Page

Tags: magento

Hi I have just made a custom layout for my home page which is working well.

But when I try to apply this layout to the home page of my second site it fails to take effect. The layout for the page reads "new 3 col layout" but on the frontend it is still display the old layout which was two cols left.

In an attempt to rectify this issue I have flushed all possible cache and have checked the scope but everything seems fine.

Has anyone had a similar problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What solved it for me in the end was changing the url for the original page and copying all its content into a new page but this time selecting the new layout.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Cms > Pages > (find home page by url_key home) > Design Tab > Layout` then choose `3 columns` and save the page.

Comment: Yeah I had done this and the backend was showing the correct layout saved for the page but it did not change the frontend. In the end I had to delete the page and recreate it with the correct template and it took effect instantly